# Getting Date Time value in Firebase Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the date time value of the server and I've implemented the code below. However, the return value of the time is sometimes null and sometimes not working as expected.

The main reason for the https request code is to check if the code has already run today so that it does not duplicate its action.

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!")
    const database = ref.child('Admins/currentDate')
    const timeStamp = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    const currentTime = new Date(timeStamp)
    const currentDate = currentTime.getDate().toString
    const currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth().toString
    const currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear().toString
    const dateFormat = currentDate + " " + currentMonth + " " + currentYear
    database.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
            const appTime = data.val().currentTime
            if(appTime === dateFormat){
                console.log("Points already added today." + dateFormat)
            }
            else{
                console.log("All points successfully updated." + dateFormat)
                data.ref.update({currentTime : dateFormat})
                .catch(console.error)
                udpateAllPoints()
            }
        })
    }).catch(console.error)
})
```

NOTE: `updateAllPoints()` is used to increase all the user points by 10% [This code works as expected]

```
function udpateAllPoints(){
    const database = ref.child('Users')
    database.once('value').then( function (snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function (data){
            const points = data.val().points
            const updatedPoints = updatePoints(points)
            const userId = data.key
            data.ref.update({ points : updatedPoints})
            .catch(console.error)
            console.log("This User "+ userId +"has "+points+ "points. \n")
        })

    }).catch(console.error)

}
```

Current Sample Output of dateFormat are something like these:

1. When the above code is run

   ```
   function toString() { [native code] } function toString() { [native code] } function toString() { [native code] }
   ```
2. When removed toString

   ```
   function { [native code] } function  { [native code] } function  { [native code] }
   ```
3. When use Date.Now() or new Date() instead of new Date(timeStamp)

   ```
   NaN NaN NaN
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a response before performing the rest of the work of your function.  This is not going to work.  Cloud Functions terminates your code almost immediately after your send a response.  This means that your database work might never occur.

What you should do instead is send the response only after all the asynchronous work is complete.  Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().

Comment: I've tried putting the res.redirect after the work but still its not giving me the date time value correctly. However even though without moving down the res.redirect, the functions  `updateAllPoints()`  is still called

Comment: i just kept getting the date value as `function toString() { [native code] } function toString() { [native code] } function toString() { [native code] }  ` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
const currentTime = await new Date()
    const currentDate = currentTime.getDate()
    const currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth()+1
    const currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear()
    const dateFormat = currentDate + " " + currentMonth + " " + currentYear
```

`toString` is not needed and the output is what I expected